# How to bundle values into set length lists in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fold

Trying to write a function in Haskell that bundles a list of xs into lists of size n e.g. the result of `bundle 3 [1..10]` should be `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10]]`.

I know the type should be

```
bundle :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

and needs to satisfy something like

```
concat $ bundle n xs == xs
length xss > 1 ==> all (\xs -> n  == length xs) (init xss)
```

but when I come to actually try to implement it I get stuck. I imagine I need to use foldl but can't think of what function to apply.

Comment: Try with your own recursion first, then use `foldl` (if applicable at all).

Comment: You could use `unfoldr` along with `splitAt`.

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.1/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf

Comment: @Bergi thanks recursion was the right way to go, think this should work `bundle :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
bundle _ [] = []
bundle n xs = take n xs : bundle n (drop n xs)`

Comment: Yes. You can do a bit better by using [`splitAt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:splitAt) instead of `take`+`drop`, but ultimately this solution is much easier than a `fold` with counters.

Comment: You don't need the `length xss > 1 ==>`. `all p [] = True`. On the other hand, your test doesn't fully specify the function--can you see its weak spot?

Comment: Also, `foldl` would be lousy here. You could do it well with `foldr`, but you'd need that fold to produce a *function*. This is a common technique, but it sounds like you're probably not ready for it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use `splitAt`, e.g.

```
bundle :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
bundle _ [] = []
bundle n xs = as : bundle n bs
  where (as, bs) = splitAt n xs
```

however, you should make sure `n` is positive, otherwise you'll end up with an infinite list of empty lists. This function holds your properties: `splitAt n` returns a pair where the first part of the tuple has exactly `n` elements. Since all but the last list entry are created that way, your second property holds. The first property holds for obvious reasons.

However, those "bundles" are usually called "chunks". The package `split` provides the fitting function `chunksOf`, which does exactly the same:

```
import Data.List.Split (chunksOf)

bundle :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
bundle = chunksOf
```